# As an editor of the channel,upload videos to youtube using Youtube API

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to upload Youtube videos as an editor(the Owner has granted access to my google account) of the channel using the code that i copied from [this tutorial](https://learndataanalysis.org/how-to-upload-a-video-to-youtube-using-youtube-data-api-in-python/) ,but the videos are always uploaded to my own channel (not the owner channel).

I have added "onBehalfOfContentOwner" and "onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel"to the request_body, and used the OAuth 2.0 keys and client_secret.json file of the Owner google cloud account. But nothing changes.

```
from Google import Create_Service #the Google.py code is below
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = r'client_secret_banana.json'
API_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

def get_video_data(video_name,video_description,video_tags,video_file):
    request_body = {
      'snippet': {
        'title': video_name,
        'description': video_description,
        'tags': video_tags,
        "categoryId": "28"#categoryID taken from this list https://gist.github.com/dgp/1b24bf2961521bd75d6c
                 },
      'status': {
        'privacyStatus': 'private',
        'selfDeclaredMadeForKids': False, 
                 },
      'notifySubscribers': False,
      "onBehalfOfContentOwner": "this is Owner Youtube user ID", #taken from this  https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced
      "onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel":"this is Owner Youtube Channel ID"
                   }

    mediaFile = MediaFileUpload(video_file)

    response_upload = service.videos().insert(part='snippet,status',
    body=request_body,
    media_body=mediaFile).execute()

    service.thumbnails().set(videoId=response_upload.get('id'),
    media_body=MediaFileUpload('banana.jpeg')).execute()

 get_video_data("test video name","test video description",["test","tags","banana"],"banana.mp4")
```

this is the Google.py file from the [tutorial](https://learndataanalysis.org/how-to-upload-a-video-to-youtube-using-youtube-data-api-in-python/)

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import datetime 

def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

I think i had missed something realy basic here, can someone recommend a solution to uploading videos to Owner Youtube channel as a editor ? Thank you!

Comment: Remove the pickle file (or else just rename it), for to run to successful completion a fresh OAuth 2 authentication/authorization flow. Make sure that you choose the proper channel (i.e. YouTube account) when the Web UI prompts you for that. No need to use `onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel`.